# Sorting a filtered list

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model

I have a list of reports that are being shown to the user. I have a-tags that allow the list to be sorted in different ways (last posted, highest upvotes etc.), and I also have separate a-tags that filter down the list according to a particular report variable (report status is open, closed etc.).

I am trying to figure a way out to allow the filter to remain in place when the a-tag to sort the list is pressed, and vice-versa.

What I have tried was setting up a model with the *statusId* (id set to filter the list) and *sortString* (string containing *"highest_award"* or *"last_update",* used to sort the list in HomeController), but my thinking was completely off.

Is there a clean way to go about this?

**Index.cshtml**

```
//List of sorting options -- *These are links that allow the user to sort the list as appropriate*
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortString="@ViewData["AwardSort"]">Highest Awarded</a></li>
    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortString="@ViewData["UpdateSort"]">Last Updated</a></li>    
</ul>

...

//Filtering options set to status.Id -- *These are buttons that allow the user to filter the list as appropriate according to a set statusId for each article*
@foreach (ReportStatus status in Model.Statuses)
{
<li class="nav-item fs-5">
    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-statusId="@status.Id">@status.StatusName</a>
</li>
}

...

//Report contents as viewed by used
@{
foreach (ReportViewModel report in Model.Reports.ReportViewModels)
{
    ...some "report" details
}
```

**HomeController.cs** *(with no mention towards filtering the list)*

```
        public IActionResult Index(string sortString/*, int statusId*/)
        {
            Console.Write(sortString + " " + statusId + "\n");

            var reports = from r in _myRepository.GetAllReports()
                          select r;

            ViewData["AwardSort"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortString) ? "highest_award" : "";
            ViewData["UpdateSort"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortString) ? "last_update" : "";

            //reports = reports.Where(r => r.StatusId == statusId); -- Need to set this and keep set

            switch (sortString)
            {
                case "last_update":
                    reports = reports.OrderBy(r => r.DateOfUpdate);
                    break;
                case "highest_award":
                    reports = reports.OrderBy(r => r.NumberOfStars);
                    break;
            }

            HallOfFameViewModel hofViewModel = new HallOfFameViewModel(_myRepository.GetTopUsers(5));
            ReportListViewModel reportsViewModel = new ReportListViewModel(
                reports.ToList(),
                _myRepository.GetUserById(_userManager.GetUserId(User))
            );

            var model = new HomePageViewModel(hofViewModel, reportsViewModel, _myRepository.GetReportStatuses());
            return View(model);
        }

//-------------------------------------------
//The filtered list would be taken here, need to somehow add currently selected sort option as well as be able to set the sorting criteria

[ResponseCache(Duration = 2)]
        [Route("Home/Index/{id}")]
        public IActionResult Index(int statusId)
        {
            var reports = from r in _nemesysRepository.GetAllReports()
                          select r;

            HallOfFameViewModel hofViewModel = new HallOfFameViewModel(_nemesysRepository.GetTopUsers(10));
            ReportListViewModel reportsViewModel = new ReportListViewModel(
                _nemesysRepository.GetAllReportsWithStatus(statusId).ToList(),
                _nemesysRepository.GetUserById(_userManager.GetUserId(User))
            );

            var model = new HomePageViewModel(hofViewModel, reportsViewModel, _nemesysRepository.GetReportStatuses());
            return View(model);
        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps combine the sort and filters into a single model

Comment: @jspcal I've tried something to that degree but at some point it became completely convoluted (very new to asp-net, barely knew what it actually was 3 days ago) and completely abandoned it. I tried finding some examples of it online to compare to but was unable to find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like below:

```
public IActionResult Index(string sortString,int statusId)
{
    if (statusId!=0)
    {
        reports = test.Reports.ReportViewModels.Where(a => a.Id == statusId);
        var data = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Filter");
        if(data!=null)
        {
            sortString = data;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewData["AwardSort"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortString) ? "highest_award" : "";
        ViewData["UpdateSort"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortString) ? "last_update" : "";
        if(sortString!=null)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Filter", sortString);
        }
    }           
    switch (sortString)
    {
        case "last_update":
            reports = reports.OrderBy(r => r.DateOfUpdate);
            break;
        case "highest_award":
            reports = reports.OrderBy(r => r.NumberOfStars);
            break;
    }
    //....

    return View(model);
}
```

Here is my whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public Report Reports { get; set; }
    public List<ReportStatus> Statuses { get; set; }
}
public class ReportStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
}
public class Report
{
    public IEnumerable<ReportViewModel> ReportViewModels { get; set; }
}
public class ReportViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfUpdate { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfStars { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Test
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortString="@ViewData["AwardSort"]">Highest Awarded</a></li>
    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortString="@ViewData["UpdateSort"]">Last Updated</a></li>
</ul>
@foreach (ReportStatus status in Model.Statuses)
{
    <li class="nav-item fs-5">
        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-statusId="@status.Id">@status.StatusName</a>
    </li>
}
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (ReportViewModel report in Model.Reports.ReportViewModels)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => report.DateOfUpdate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => report.NumberOfStars)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    Test test = new Test()
    {
        Reports = new Report()
        {
            ReportViewModels = new List<ReportViewModel>()
            {
                new ReportViewModel(){ Id=1, DateOfUpdate=new DateTime(2018,2,12),NumberOfStars=34},
                new ReportViewModel(){Id=1,DateOfUpdate=new DateTime(2019,3,23),NumberOfStars=23},
                new ReportViewModel(){Id=2,DateOfUpdate=new DateTime(2014,5,13),NumberOfStars=25},
                new ReportViewModel(){Id=2,DateOfUpdate=new DateTime(2015,2,24),NumberOfStars=29}
            }
        },
        Statuses= new List<ReportStatus>()
        {
            new ReportStatus(){Id=1,StatusName="aa"},
            new ReportStatus(){Id=2,StatusName="bb"}
        }
    };
    public IActionResult Index(string sortString,int statusId)
    {
        var reports = test.Reports.ReportViewModels;

        if (statusId!=0)
        {
            reports = test.Reports.ReportViewModels.Where(a => a.Id == statusId);
            var data = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Filter");
            if(data!=null)
            {
                sortString = data;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["AwardSort"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortString) ? "highest_award" : "";
            ViewData["UpdateSort"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortString) ? "last_update" : "";
            if(sortString!=null)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Filter", sortString);
            }
        }           
        switch (sortString)
        {
            case "last_update":
                reports = reports.OrderBy(r => r.DateOfUpdate);
                break;
            case "highest_award":
                reports = reports.OrderBy(r => r.NumberOfStars);
                break;
        }
        test.Reports.ReportViewModels = reports;

        return View(test);
    }
}
```

Be sure register Session:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSession();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSession();       
}
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-session-state

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, but this misses my main concern. I have more order sorts in place that do as you suggested, didn't add them as they were irrelevant to the issue.

My issue is that I have buttons, shown above under comment "//Filtering options set to status.Id" which filters my list down according to the id of each report. So, if statusId = 1, only reports with this id are shown.

What I was asking is I can also save the current sort option onto this 'filtered' list as well, and be able to sort the filtered list as well. I have amended the question to better show this.

Comment: Hi @KristianDeFilippis, You could use Session to store the latest sort string. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved the issue! As a side note, since I am using two Index methods, with the second one redirecting the filtered lists (`[Route("Home/Index/{id}")]`), since I can't send sortString though `<a ... asp-route-statusId="@status.Id">@status.StatusName</a>`, is there a way to set `asp-route-sortString` through the `<li><a ... asp-route-sortString="@ViewData["sortOption"]">Sort</a></li>` while remaining in the `Home/Index/{id}`? Sorry if this may be trivial, I've just started learning programming on my own this year.

Comment: Hi @KristianDeFilippis, no need using two method, actually combine them to one method will well performed, otherwise the code will be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

my friend,
You should also add a 'CurrentFilterName' for each filter tag you have.
Ex: ViewData["AwardSort"] should couple with ViewData["CurrentAwardSort"]
So when the page reloads when a filter is clicked you send the values to this 'FilterName'
and on input value, you put 'CurrentFilteNameValue'.
Hopefully, this solves your issue. Wish you the best :)

Comment: Didn't understand how the ViewData would keep the information on the current set sort option. Could you kindly explain further?